# Can the GUI daemon and the CLI daemon share the same data-dir at the same time?

Tags: monero-wallet-cli, monerod, monero-wallet-gui, blockchain-data

Can the GUI daemon and the CLI daemon share the same data-dir at the same time? Both running simultaneously?

Comment: Not an answer to your question but FYI you don't need to run separate daemons for gui and cli. They can connect to same daemon.